# table persistent_logins en spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to remember my spring session security when I view tutorials, I noticed that spring stores the security token in the persistent_logins table. 
Is what I have to create it myself this table or this is the framework that will create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security framework will *not* create the table for you, you have to create it yourself, or use a library like [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/). You can find SQL in the [Spring Security Reference Appendix](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#persistent-login-remember-me-schema).